# Ошибка urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, chromedriver

Пробую запустить скрипт на ubunty20 с парсингом avito с помощью undetected_chromedriver но выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "main.py", line 856, in <module>
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     parser()
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "main.py", line 646, in parser
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=119,headless=True)
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py>
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     self.patcher.auto()
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/undetected_chromedriver/patcher.py">
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     self.unzip_package(self.fetch_package())
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/undetected_chromedriver/patcher.py">
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     return urlretrieve(download_url)[0]
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     response = meth(req, response)
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     response = self.parent.error(
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     return self._call_chain(*args)
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     result = func(*args)
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]:     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
Nov 06 14:45:52 2162313-av13306.twc1.net python3[11847]: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Запускал на windows 10 все работает прекрасно

Код:

```
url_ob = f'https://www.avito.ru/stavropol/kvartiry/prodam/vtorichka-ASgBAgICAkSSA8YQ5geMUg?context=H4sIAAAAAAAA_0q0MrSqLraysFJKK8rPDUhMT1WyLrYyNLNSKk5NLErOcMsvyg3PTElPLVGyrgUEAAD__xf8iH4tAAAA&s=104'
    driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=119,headless=True)

    driver.get(url_ob)
    html_ob = driver.page_source
```

Пробовал даже менять ссылку, хотя на нее он не жалуется.
В чем может быть проблема